# google map infoBoxes doesn't pop up consistently during mouseover

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jsf, google-maps-api-3, jsf-1.2

I have a google map embedded in xhtml.  It has markers with popup InfoBoxes that I converted from InfoWindows to take advantage of layout control, but now I'm getting some inconsistent behavior.  When the page first loads the infoBoxes all open normally with mouseover.  But as I move around the map or move the cursor off the map and back on, they start behaving badly, sometimes they work, sometimes not.

```
 /* map stuff */

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 4,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.40, -91.32),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
});



google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
map.setZoom( map.getZoom() );

 var marker;


 /* load each marker with info */

function addEvents(lat, lng, markerInfo) {        


 /* set each marker */  

       marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
         map: map
       });

   var iconFile = '#{request.contextPath}/img/pin.png'; 
    marker.setIcon(iconFile); 

 /* infoBox properties - tried moving this to global, doesn't work */
    var boxOpts = {
            disableAutoPan: false,
            maxWidth: 0,
            pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0),
            boxStyle: { 
              background: '#ffffff',
              opacity: 1,
              width: '180px'
            },
            closeBoxURL: '',
            infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
            isHidden: false,
            pane: 'floatPane',
            enableEventPropagation: true
    };

 var infobox = new InfoBox(boxOpts);
 var html = '<div style="color:#333; font-size:12px; box-shadow: 12px 12px 8px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);">' markerInfo + '</div>';


 /* mouseover shows infoBox - only works sometimes, tried addListener as well */

   google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(){
       infobox.setContent(html);
       infobox.open(map, this);
  });

   google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker, 'mouseout', function(){
       infobox.close(map, this);

   });
}
```

the addEvents function is called here:

```
 <div id="myController" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <rich:dataList var="eventAdd" value="#{some.resultList}">
  <script type="text/javascript">
         addEvents('<h:outputText value="#{eventAdd.latitude}"/>', 
           '<h:outputText value="#{eventAdd.longitude}"/>',                             
           '<h:outputText value="#{eventAdd.markerInfo}"/>
     );
     </script>
```

There doesn't appear to be any pattern to why some work and some don't, it's not always the same ones.  I can mouseover one and the infoBox shows, move to another and it doesn't, move back to the previous one and it doesn't show either.
ETA:
When I go back to InfoWindow, the popups show as expected.

Comment: Is there anything in the console?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or a link that will reproduce the issue?  Seems similar to problems I have seen reported in the past, can't find those references right now.

Comment: @alkis, yes there is. When I select a marker I get 

Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'FILTER'.  Declaration dropped.
a4j/s/3_3_3.Final/org/richfaces/skin.xcs/DATB/eAFb88PeNXT5DGkAE5cD2A__
Line 1
I'll try a fiddle but I don't think I can get the richFaces stuff in there

Comment: If I remove opacity: 1 from boxOpts those errors go away, but the inconsistency remains.